# Python - Local bone rotation issue in Game Logic

Tags: python, game-engine

Background: I've rigged a jointed hand and I'm having trouble rotating the joints in the local axes programatically (in the game logic area). The bone "local" axes are pointing in the direction of the bone which isn't aligned with the global axes. If I rotate them in Pose mode everything rotates correctly, with the X axis being the rotation axis for each joint.

In the following code example you can see I'm getting the input from a joystick (which works), creating a Euler vector for rotation in the X axis then applying that back to the LOCAL axis. When I run the player and move the joystick, the joint does rotate, but does so aligned with the GLOBAL axes, not the local axes.

I have printed out the Euler vectors for both the local and global axis and they are the same, which explains the result, but I have object's 'show_axis' flag set so I can see that this is not aligned with the global axes.

```
import bge.logic as logic, bpy, math, mathutils
from math import*
from mathutils import*

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
joint = cont.owner

joy = cont.sensors['Thumb.distal.R']
aXis = joy.axisValues
ang = (aXis[1] + 32768) * 180 / 32000  

eul = mathutils.Euler((math.radians(ang), 0, 0), "XYZ")
print(eul)
joint.localOrientation = eul.to_matrix()
```

If I [instead] do a apply rotation like so;

```
joint.applyRotation([math.radians(ag), 0, 0], True)
```

...with the local set to True, it does rotate in the correct axes, just by too much as this is a additive rotation, not an absolute rotation from the axis itself (I want a joint to range between it's closed and open angles.

[image: Jointed Hand]

Can someone explain where I have gone wrong and/or provide a snippet that will do what I want.

Sincerely, Paul